# How to connect to Sql Server with integrated security using JDBC (via persistence.xml)

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, jdbc

```
<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"/>
<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost/my_db"/>
<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value=""/>
<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value=""/>
<property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect"/>
<property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
```

I am trying to connect to my local `sql server` by using this piece of configurating above. `Mysql`, `oracle` and `postgresql` work fine wtihout any problem but I do not really know how to connect to sql server since I have neither username nor password for it. I wrote something like this. `"Data Source=myserver;Initial Catalog=mydb;Integrated Security=SSPI".` How do I achieve this or anoher way to connect my localhost for sql server? Thanks

Comment: what do you mean with *since I have neither username nor password for it.* ?! You can't connect to a db without user and pass

Comment: I only write my computers name and database name to connect it. I think windows authentication just let me in

Comment: @Leviand Are you aware that Microsoft SQL Server JDBC driver has support for Windows/Kerberos authentication which means you **can** connect without specifying a username and password (it will use the credentials of the user running the current process).

Comment: Yeah but its way better use a dedicated user imho...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to connect to the SQL Server instance using Windows authentication you need to add `integratedSecurity=true` to your connection URL, e.g.,

```
jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:49242;databaseName=myDb;integratedSecurity=true
```

You also need to ensure that the file "sqljdbc_auth.dll" can be found on the library path for your Java application. (One way to do that is to ensure that its location is included in the Windows `PATH` environment variable.)

Comment: The alternative Kerberos authentication does not need the native library, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/using-kerberos-integrated-authentication-to-connect-to-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017